# AOT error : ng build -prod not working

Tags: angular5, angular2-aot

If I am using ng build -prod (with AOT) I am getting the following error:

Module build failed: Error: @ngtools/webpack is being used as a loader but no `tsConfigPath` option nor AotPlugin was detected. You must provide at least one of these

But I am not using any webpack for my project.

If I am building without aot i.e., ng build -prod --aot=false everything works fine.

How can I achieve aot build without webpack. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing when I use web workers, but without web workers it works fine. Not sure what the solution is.